# React render <img> tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

For the following react code:

```
ReactDOM.render(<div className="divcss5">
   <img src={'/auto_merge_deployment.png'}
         alt="Auto Merge Deployment"
         align="bottom"
         id="auto_merge_deployment"
         style={style}>Auto Merge Deployment</img>
    <br></br>
    <p><i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"
           style={{fontSize: "1.73em"}}
    ></i>Icon</p>
</div>, document.getElementById("icon_tip_div"));
```

I got:

> Error: img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
>       in img
>       in div

Is that because the `src` is not formatted properly or the path is wrong, and it cannot find the image?

Comment: `img` is a self closing tag. It can't have any content inside it. Might be why you see this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing what went wrong is `<img>` tag should not have a closing tag, that needs to be removed first. Read from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img):

> The HTML `<img>` element embeds an image into the document.

Also in [*w3schools*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp):

> In HTML the `<img>` tag has no end tag.

I would remove the closing tag as the following:

```
<img src={'/auto_merge_deployment.png'}
     alt="Auto Merge Deployment"
     align="bottom"
     id="auto_merge_deployment"
     style={style}>Auto Merge Deployment
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
ReactDOM.render(<div className="divcss5">
   <img src={'/auto_merge_deployment.png'}
         alt="Auto Merge Deployment"
         align="bottom"
         id="auto_merge_deployment"
         style={style} />
    <br></br>
    <p><i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"
           style={{fontSize: "1.73em"}}
    ></i>Icon</p>
</div>, document.getElementById("icon_tip_div"));
```

You don't put content in an `img`, even just with normal HTML.